# Subir Archivo a base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, php7, php5

¿Como están? 
pasa que necesito subir un archivo a mi base de datos, tengo un formulario con varios campos que se guardan correctamente, pero al subir un archivo me sale el siguiente error, pero ya tengo las variables definidas, se que se puede de otras formas y ya lo he hecho pero lo necesito así de esta forma escoger el archivo y que se guarde

[image: error]

**Muestro el código** 
[image: código de campo]

**Insert**
[image: Insert]

**Tabla Mysql**
[image: tabla]

Comment: saludos debes agregar tu codigo, no captura del mismo para una mejor respuesta a posibles soluciones..!!

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener en cuenta si quieres guardar el archivo en la base de
datos para esto debes de definir en la base de datos el tipo de dato,
si quieres solo el nombre del archivo y el archivo guardarlo en una
ruta, tendrás que declarar la ruta para esto le sugiero el siguiente
código.

```
  <?php

//primero haces la conexión a la base de datos
 $conexion=mysqli_connect('direccion','root','password','bd'); 

 //aquí declaramos la ruta en donde se va a guardar el archivo 
 $directorio1="ruta/im/";//Direccion donde se guardara la PDF 

 //aquí obtiene el origen del archivo 
 $archivo1=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];//Origen 

 //aquí le asignamos un nombre al archivo file
 $nombrearchivo1=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];//Nombre archivo

 //con este if sirve para mover el archivo a la carpeta de destino 
 if(move_uploaded_file($archivo,$directorio."/".$nombrearchivo)) { 
 //en esta parte haces la consulta para ser el insert
 $sql ="INSERT INTO bd(name,archivo,description) VALUES (   '" . $_POST['nombre'] . "','" . $_POST['descripcion'] . "',   '" . 
 $_FILES['archivo']['name'] . "',   '" . $_POST['description'] . "')"; 
 echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); }else {  }
// 
?>
```

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta si quieres guardar el archivo en la base de datos para esto debes de definir en la base de datos el tipo de dato,
si quieres solo el nombre del archivo y el archivo guardarlo en una ruta, tendrás que declarar la ruta para esto le sugiero el siguiente código.